# Share OSX Yosemite updates over a network

Tags: osx-yosemite, software-update

We have about 7 networked Macs running Yosemite in an area with very poor broadband. When running the app store updates for just system applications all machine are trying to download them and clogging up the bandwidth.

Is there any method of downloading the updates on one Mac then rolling them out to the other machines?

Comment: You need to be running OS X Server to do that, afaik. You can do it for OS updates themselves though - Google for 'OS X combo update [OS number, 10.10.3 etc]'

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin I didn't know about that, really helpfull